# Stop visual studio debug putting slash in string containing double quotes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I hit this odd behavour yesterday in Visual Studio 2015 where I was making a string that started and ended with double quotes.  In stepping through the code I hovered over the result to see the contents and there were back slashes in the string - what! (see image below).  Cutting a long story short, I figured out the debug view of the variable is displaying with the escaping backslashes - which in my opinion is misleading.

Does any one know if there is a way to disable this in Visual Studio so that it just displays the value as either `""bob*""` or without indication of the string type `"bob*"` ?

[image]

P.S. Yes I know, it seems a bit newbie to be using VS for years before noticing this behavour.  Also the image is not showing our production code :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is expected. Because you are under debug mode you are given the dev version of the string.

To get a user friendly version of the string (actual value without slash) you just have to click on the magnify glass icon on the left

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a way to set which option is the default to use from the options in the magnify glass icon?

Comment: @miltonb not that im aware of