# ASP.NET / C# : variable with double quote

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET & C#, I try to declare a variable with double quote in it, for eg.

```
string str1 = @"""quote""";
```

The result I expect to get is "quote", but the result I get is "\"quote\"", can anybody help?

Comment: what is the `str1.Length` ?

Comment: Where do you see the result `"\"quote\""`?

Comment: in debug mode, where it returns error because the variable contain "\" characters

Comment: `\\`` is used as escape character to escape `"` in such use cases. They are actually not part of the actual value of the string. If you do `string str1 = @"""quote"""; Console.WriteLine(str1);` you will be `"quote"` in Console as output. What error you are getting though?

Comment: I would like to pass variable with double quote into an sql in asp.net c#, so the variable when pass into the sql, it will show the \ character, example below:

string str1 = @"""quote""";

 using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {


                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.BindByName = true;
                        cmd.CommandText = "select " + str1 + " from dual;"


the value of variable str1 in cmd.CommandText will show "\quote\"

Comment: @Kevin Hi ..I tried your code, but I got a result what you expected.

Comment: here is fiddle:https://dotnetfiddle.net/ccd5bh its getting the output what is your error

Comment: What you've done is correct.. I believe you are inspecting the string value through Quickwatch/Watch window.. If so, you will see escape character ( \ ) before every double quote inside the string.. Hope it makes sense.. just try this and see you actual value

` Console.WriteLine(str1);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop visual studio debug putting slash in string containing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172620/stop-visual-studio-debug-putting-slash-in-string-containing-double-quotes)

Comment: @Bharathi, thanks, your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is correct. I believe you are inspecting the string value through QuickWatch/Watch window. If so, you will see escape character `\` before every double quote inside the string. Just try this and see you actual value.

```
Console.WriteLine(str1);
```

If you want to see a proper string (without `\`), click on the magnify glass icon on the left in QuickWatch pop-up.