# Unable to remove backslashes from my String in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, transform

I'm creating a application where the user can choose if their output is JSON or XML, the original output is JSON. When the user chooses for XML I want to convert my JSON output into XML. This I do with the following code:

```
//create responsestring
string mappedResponse = obj.ToString();

//create new xml document with root insert response string
XmlDocument jsonToXml = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(mappedResponse, "root");

//get inner xml in string
string XmlString = jsonToXml.InnerXml.ToString();

//return entire inner xml
return new HttpResponseMessage
{
     Content = new StringContent(XmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
};
```

However I'm getting the following error:

[image]

The string causing the error looks like this:

[image]

So when I try to turn my JObject in a String its filling the string with "\" and "\r\n". How can I prevent or remove this?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried using string.replace("\r\n\", String.empty), however this does only work for the "\r\n" data. The string will still have some "\" in the string at the '"' from the JSON.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Long story short: those backslashes are how the debugger displays the string. Click the magnifying glass for the real string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172620/stop-visual-studio-debug-putting-slash-in-string-containing-double-quotes) for more details. I did mark your question as a duplicate, but have reopened it so that someone can answer the real issue (or find an appropriate existing question). I recommend editing your question to focus on that.

Comment: That string contains `\"` which just escapes the double quotes, look for an actual `/` which the error says it finds.

Comment: `'/'` is a different character than `'\'`. The error you showed in the exception states about a `'/'` character not being able to be included in a name. From the code you showed it's probably cause here in the line `Content = new StringContent(XmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")`. Can you check that?

Comment: You show an Exception being caught by a `catch`, but we need the code that is in the `try { ... } ` block because that is where the Exception happens. Please **[edit]** the question and add the `try { ... }` block into your sample code.