# Correct use of StringBuilder with JSON content inside

Tags: c#, json, stringbuilder

I'm struggling about this case.
I receive data in JSON format from NetworkStream and I put it in a StringBuilder:

```
   buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];  
   bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
   myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
```

Below the content of the myCompleteMessage (note the char "~"):

```
"\"{\\\"id\\\": 0, \\\"contour\\\": [[[323, 377]], [[230, 479]], [[283, 436]]], \\\"measureA\\\": 18.694646183289144, \\\"measureB\\\": 197.76944936476116, \\\"image\\\": \\\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF4AAABnCAIAAAAGxWJcAAAgAElEQVR4AQHdcSKOAatVmwEBAQb+CQUFBQYGBgEBAQAF//7+/v3//vv7+/z2+gAAAP39/f39/QAC/wAAAAH/AAEBAf7+AAEBAQAAAAEBAQEDAP///wICAgAAAAIAAf7+/gEBAQAAAP4A/v7+/gMDAwAAAP0A/QAAAAAAAAAAAP0C/v///wAAAAEBAf8I//z8/P4F\\\"}~\"\"{\\\"id\\\": 4, \\\"contour\\\": [[[570, 163]], [[585, 169]], [[606, 157]], [[599, 153]], [[581, 164]], [[577, 160]], [[586, 145]], [[608, 151]], [[614, 147]], [[583, 140]]], \\\"measureA\\\": 37.742413753208304, \\\"measureB\\\": 65.91583997176758, \\\"image\\\": \\\"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\\\"}"
```

Now, I split this string above matching the char "~":

```
    var jsonList = myCompleteMessage.ToString().Split('~');
```

And with a foreach loop I take the JSON string element in myCompleteMessage, pass it to SimpleJSON parser and do something:

```
    foreach (string jsonRow in jsonList)
    {
       JSONNode data = JSONNode.Parse(jsonRow);
   
       do something
    }
```

But the parser return an exception telling the string is not JSON format.

Where I'm wrong?

---

The value of `myCompleteMessage` shown above is as it is displayed by Visual Studio.  When I [click on the magnifier glass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172656/3744182) or do `Debug.WriteLine(myCompleteMessage)` I see:

not have the magnifier glass to click on, then I clicked on the magnifier glass on jsonlist variable. Below the content:

```
"{\"id\": 0, \"contour\": [[[323, 377]], [[230, 479]], [[283, 436]]], \"measureA\": 18.694646183289144, \"measureB\": 197.76944936476116, \"image\": \"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"}
```

Comment: Your input JSON is not  valid JSON , and you should not edit JSON using stringbuilder.

Comment: Why it's not a valid json? Server side there is a Python script that send that string converting to json format. What's possible? And if not edit with stringbuilder with other? Thanks and sorry for this questions.

Comment: Just use newtonsoft.json parser, and serialize it into an object, then make whatever you need to do, and then deserialize, if you need to return the modifications back.

Comment: Looking at the first 3 charachters:  A json does not start with a `\\"`, and should not (normally contain `\"` (at least not at that position)

Comment: This is not a valid json. Starts with \" and has ~ in it along with multiple escaped strings. You need to fix how the json is sent (not serialized twice) and then try to read it. There are multiple objects but no seperation (commas) or square brackets (to identify it as list)

Comment: @MortenBork thanks. Do you intend to use newtonsoft.json parser to server side too? Or to client side only?

Comment: While the string shown in your question is well-formed JSON (I uploaded it to https://jsonlint.com/ to check) it is a **JSON string literal**, not an array or object.  Did you possibly receive double-serialized JSON?  Or did you copy the string into the question with Visual Studio escaping added?  Can you double-check the contents of `myCompleteMessage` and ensure that your question includes the "raw" JSON without Visual Studio escaping?

Comment: @dbc in the Python server side there is: data = json.dumps(datastr) AND conn.sendall(datas.encode())
I don't know if these code lines double serialize JSON

Comment: @Kafar - We need to know the raw contents of `myCompleteMessage` on the client side, without VIsual Studio escaping.  To see the raw contents see e.g. [Stop visual studio debug putting slash in string containing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41172620/3744182).  Or just `Debug.WriteLine(myCompleteMessage)`.

Comment: @dbc I answered to your reply.

Comment: Well that is still double-serialized (just not triple-serialized I guess).  You might want to fix that on the server side.  If you need help doing that you should [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a second question and include a [mcve] showing the server code that generates the error.

Comment: Also, are you parsing the JSON using [SimpleJSON](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) in [tag:unity3d]?

Comment: There is a quote missing at the end as well !!

Comment: @Jawad is correct.  The original escaped string was a well-formed JSON string literal, but the unescaped value for `myCompleteMessage` is malformed JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error.  You won't be able to parse that with any JSON parser.

Comment: Whatever the python script is doing, we technically don't care about, you marked this question C#, Json and StringBuilder, NOT Python. 

Second -> If the issue is on the python side, unit test the python script,. 
If the error is on the C# side, unit test the C# side... 

The string being passed through http, is just a string, in the json format. Anything else, is purely related to how you write it in or out. Obviously, the Newtonsoft component should only be used on the C#, I don't even know if the component is available in python. 

But use a component for serialization.

Comment: writing your own serializer is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the JSON is in incorrect format

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = "\"{\\\"id\\\": 0, \\\"contour\\\": [[[323, 377]], [[230, 479]], [[283, 436]]], \\\"measureA\\\": 18.694646183289144, \\\"measureB\\\": 197.76944936476116, \\\"image\\\": \\\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF4AAABnCAIAAAAGxWJcAAAgAElEQVR4AQHdcSKOAatVmwEBAQb+CQUFBQYGBgEBAQAF//7+/v3//vv7+/z2+gAAAP39/f39/QAC/wAAAAH/AAEBAf7+AAEBAQAAAAEBAQEDAP///wICAgAAAAIAAf7+/gEBAQAAAP4A/v7+/gMDAwAAAP0A/QAAAAAAAAAAAP0C/v///wAAAAEBAf8I//z8/P4F\\\"}~\"\"{\\\"id\\\": 4, \\\"contour\\\": [[[570, 163]], [[585, 169]], [[606, 157]], [[599, 153]], [[581, 164]], [[577, 160]], [[586, 145]], [[608, 151]], [[614, 147]], [[583, 140]]], \\\"measureA\\\": 37.742413753208304, \\\"measureB\\\": 65.91583997176758, \\\"image\\\": \\\"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\\\"}";

                JObject test = JObject.Parse(json);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 400.

Comment: Ok, now I reposted the content of jsonList unless Visual Studio escaping

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        try
        {
            string json = myCompleteMessage;

            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);
            Console.WriteLine(data.id);
            Console.WriteLine(data.contour);
            Console.WriteLine(data.measureA);
            Console.WriteLine(data.measureB);
            Console.WriteLine(data.image);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```