# Delete \ from string C#

Tags: c#, string, trim

I need to delete `\`, `"`, `[` and `]` from this string:

```
"[\"30001|410000000|400000000|PocketPC_Login|1\",\"30002|420000000|400000000|PocketPC_ChangementZone|1\",\"30003|430000000|400000000|PocketPC_Transactions|1\",\"30004|440000000|400000000|PocketPC_Gestion|1\",\"30005|450000000|400000000|PocketPC_Administration|0\",\"30006|431000000|430000000|PocketPC_TSEntrees|1\"]"
```

When I do this:

```
string.Trim(new Char[] { '"', '[', ']', "\\"})
```

or this:

```
string.Trim(new Char[] { '"', '[', ']', Convert.ToChar(92)})
```

the result is always the same:

```
"30001|410000000|400000000|PocketPC_Login|1\",\"30002|420000000|400000000|PocketPC_ChangementZone|1\",\"30003|430000000|400000000|PocketPC_Transactions|1\",\"30004|440000000|400000000|PocketPC_Gestion|1\",\"30005|450000000|400000000|PocketPC_Administration|0\",\"30006|431000000|430000000|PocketPC_TSEntrees|1"
```

The `\` and `"` still there. What could I do?

Comment: `Trim` only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string.  You want `Replace`.

Comment: The slash isn't actually part of your string.  Your debugger is just showing that the inner quotes are escaped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop visual studio debug putting slash in string containing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172620/stop-visual-studio-debug-putting-slash-in-string-containing-double-quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim only removes items at the start or the end of a string.   You should use a chain of string.Replace.

```
myString
   .Replace("\\", String.Empty)
   .Replace("\"", String.Empty)
   .Replace("[", String.Empty)
   .Replace("]", String.Empty);
```

Something else I just noticed, is that your data is likely to be JSON (the square brackets `[]` suggest that you have an array of strings).