# When pulling data from DB, '\' character keeps getting added to my string

Tags: c#, string

I have a long string stored in my DB. When I inspect it in VS it adds `'\'` characters everywhere. What is causing this?

[image]

[image]

I am expecting no `'\'` characters to come back

Comment: **It isn't** adding backslashes to your strings: that's just the _debugger display_, it doesn't shows in-memory strings literally the way that the Memory window does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172620/stop-visual-studio-debug-putting-slash-in-string-containing-double-quotes

Answer (score 1):

It's returned a JSON object, and wrapped your strings (both field labels and data contents) with quotes - these quotes are escaped, so you don't see the backslashes.

Json fields have quotes, so this looks like working as intended?